# awk, print all columns and add new column with substr

Tags: awk

I have this table

```
USI,Name,2D-3D
RO0001,Patate,2D
RO0002,Haricot,3D
RO0003,Banane,2D
RO0004,Pomme,2D
RO0005,Poire,2D
```

and I want this

```
USI,Name,2D-3D
RO0001,Patate,2D,RO_2D_Patate
RO0002,Haricot,3D,RO_3D_Haricot
RO0003,Banane,2D,RO_2D_Banane
RO0004,Pomme,2D,RO_2D_Pomme
RO0005,Poire,2D,RO_2D_Poire
```

I manage to obtain the construction "RO_2D_Patate" with awk

```
awk -F "," '{print substr($1,1,2)"_"substr($3,1,2)"_"$2}' Test4.txt
```

But I want to print all my column $0 before as my second table.

I tried everything But I am still a novice !!!!

Any idea over there?

Comment: Please use code tags for sample Input_file and expected output in your posts/.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '{print $0 (NR>1 ? FS substr($1,1,2)"_"$3"_"$2 : "")}' Test4.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and I don't anderstand why but my result is different. Where I made a mistake ? I obtain this "_PatatePatate, 2D"  the same for the other and I don't have my 3 column before ...

Comment: Most likely your input file contains control-Ms (typical in Windows-generated files). Run `dos2unix` or similar on your file before running awk or any other UNIx tool on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1{$4=substr($1,1,2)"_"$3"_"$2}1' Test4.txt
USI,Name,2D-3D
RO0001,Patate,2D,RO_2D_Patate
RO0002,Haricot,3D,RO_3D_Haricot
RO0003,Banane,2D,RO_2D_Banane
RO0004,Pomme,2D,RO_2D_Pomme
RO0005,Poire,2D,RO_2D_Poire
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have exactly the same problem above.  I tried and I don't anderstand why but my result is different. Where I made a mistake ? I obtain this "_PatatePatate, 2D" the same for the other and I don't have my 3 column before ...

Comment: Check your input file, is it consistent with what you post. Because both Ed's answer and my answer work fine here.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{print $0,substr($1,1,2)"_"$NF"_"$2}/USI/' OFS=, file

USI,Name,2D-3D
RO0001,Patate,2D,RO_2D_Patate
RO0002,Haricot,3D,RO_3D_Haricot
RO0003,Banane,2D,RO_2D_Banane
RO0004,Pomme,2D,RO_2D_Pomme
RO0005,Poire,2D,RO_2D_Poire
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please edit your post and also add a short explanation what your command does and why it solves the initial problem.